# Expressão Regulares REGEX AJUDA

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Tenho uma array no servidor em Nodejs, estou percorrendo arquivos html e preciso retornar o valor que se encontra no meio da tag span usando uma expressao regular como ficaria ?

```
{
< span class="filteredAds"> de teste< /span>,

< span class="filteredAds"> de teste23< /span>>

}
```

Não se sabe o que pode vir no meio da tag após o de.

Alguem pode me dar uma ajuda ?

Comment: Não pode pegar pela classe, id ou tag ?

Comment: Evite regex para processar HTML. Expressões regulares não são uma boa ferramenta para isso. Você devia considerar usar alguma extensão para fazer isso por você ([jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)) e, como @MagicHat sugeriu, capturar os elementos pela classe ou tag.

Comment: Quando estava realizando a tarefa estava no back end, não no front end.

Answer (score 4):

Sugestão:

```js
const regex = /<[^\/]*span[^>]*>[^<]+</g;
const subRegex = />([^<]+)</;
const string = `{
< span class="filteredAds"> de teste< /span>,

< span class="filteredAds"> de teste23< /span>>

}`;
const conteudo = string.match(regex).map(str => str.match(/>([^<]+)</).pop().trim());
console.log(conteudo); // ["de teste","de teste23"]
```

A ideia é dividir em dois passos: capturar cada span, extrair o conteúdo. Quando uso `[^<]` na regex isso quer dizer: qualquer caracter, excepto `<`.